# Start recording with delay and stop early

Tags: audacity

I'm new to audacity (and recording) and mostly love it. But there is one problem I face when I record myself reading. I tend to make pauses quite often, so I interrupt the recording with `space` and start it again with `R`.
Unfortunately, hitting these keys is audible so I have to manually cut them out or mute them, which is kinda tedious. Is there a way to prevent the sounds from hitting a key, such as start recording with a delay and neglecting the last bit before stopping a recording?

...and no, less pressure on the keys is not an option ;)

Answer (score 0):

You can use a tool such as Sox to trim both ends of the recording. 500ms should do the trick.

Comment: thank you, @Mark! Removing the key stroke sounds at the beginning and the end of the whole recording is easy in Audacity as well. What makes it tedious is that I have many of these sounds within the recording as well (whenever I have stopped the recording and started it again (thus appending to the existing recording)).

Comment: Is there some sort of GPIO remote trigger you can activate to start/stop that doesn't rely on a keypress?

Comment: No, I don't have a remote trigger and I was hoping that it is possible solve this problem using software (e.g. an setting in audacity or a plugin). Thanks for your hint, but I think I prefer the tedious cutting/muting to buying something which will get obsolete once this functionality is built into some software ^^

Comment: @yogabonito - it usually doesn't need to be built in to software, as folks use remote triggers. You could even get yourself a silent keyboard for this if you wanted to.

Comment: Thank you Rory! Unfortunately I am still reluctant to buy stuff, as I am not a professional ^^

Comment: "Professional" isn't about how much gear you have, it's about what you know about what you can do with the gear you do have.

Answer (score 0):

Simple solution is to use a silent external keyboard and place it as far away from the mic as possible.